# What to do with these posts on the "Batman equation" question?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, deletion, answers

These three posts ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real/54623#54623), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real/54633#54633), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real/54538#54538)) on the Batman question are certainly *not* answers to the original question. However, I'm unsure about what exactly to do with them. Here are possibilities I've thought of:

1. Delete them.
2. Convert them to comments on the question.
3. Make a community-wiki post on the question, which will collect all of them together.

I like 3 the best. Simply deleting them would be entirely justified, I think, but a lot of people who see this question are going to want to try it out for themselves, and we might as well save them the trouble of typing out the whole thing. Also, with a community wiki post, anyone can add the equations as expressed in even more languages/systems, and it can be corrected / improved by anyone (this appears to be necessary: it seems stoicfury's and John Garner's answers don't actually work. I haven't tried Mark's suggested equations on a graphing calculator yet.)

What do people want to do? Any other suggestions than the ones above?

Comment: Maybe someone should at least protect the question before it goes the way of the monkeys & shakespeare question?

Comment: A wiki answer for code to plot the "curve" in different computing environments would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've converted them to comments. They are, more or less, comments.

Comment: That had the unfortunate side effect of truncating John Garner's Mathematica transcription of the equations.